# Jump to a particular folder directly in terminal

Tags: ubuntu

I have many hierarchical folders in Ubuntu where I kept source files of my programs. Out of those a few of the folders are frequently accessed.

It is very time consuming to write the complete path in the terminal.

Is there any method to directly jump to any particular folder by very less few keystrokes?

for eg: path:  /home/user/programming/CPP/Networking/Boost/DownloadedSrc

Is there any way to directly jump to DownloadedSrc folder by saving the path somewhere in the terminal user files? Atleast for next 1 month I need to use that folder frequently.

I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
~$ alias ms='cd /home/user/programming/CPP/Networking/Boost/DownloadedSrc'
~$ ms
~/programming/CPP/Networking/Boost/DownloadedSrc$
```

other solution:

```
~$ export CDPATH=/home/user/programming/CPP/Networking/Boost/
~$ cd DownloadedSrc
~/programming/CPP/Networking/Boost/DownloadedSrc$
```

3rd solution:

```
~$ export MS=/home/user/programming/CPP/Networking/Boost/DownloadedSrc
~$ cd $MS
~/programming/CPP/Networking/Boost/DownloadedSrc$
```